# Access WPF Name properties in static method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application. In one of the XAML I have used Name attribute like as follows

```
 x:Name="switchcontrol"
```

I have to access the control/property in .cs file using `this.switchcontrol`
My question is, I need to access the control in static method like

```
public static getControl()
{
 var control = this.switchcontrol;//some thing like that
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`this` is not accessible in static method. You can try save reference to your instance in static property, for example:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{

    public static MyWindow Instance { get; private set;}

    public MyWindow() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // save value
        Instance = this; 
    }

    public static getControl()
    {
        // use value
        if (Instance != null)
            var control = Instance.switchcontrol; 
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        Instance = null; // remove reference, so GC could collect it, but you need to be sure there is only one instance!!
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow.  Thanks a lot. It works. Just for curiosity, is there any disadvantages using this approach?

Comment: @anees Yes, there is one, if you have more than one instance, then you will get control of last created window. And you need to clear Instance value, see my updated answer.

Comment: But, I need to create only one instance.. So Shall I proceed with old one?

Comment: @anees Yes, I think you can :)

Comment: Great! Accepted your answer.  Can you let me know why 'this' operator is not accessible inside static method?

Comment: @anees Because "this" is a reference to the class instance your method is defined in. But in a static method, there is no instance because no instance is required to call the method. So "this" is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives to Tony's method - you could pass in the window (or whatever xaml construct you are using) as a reference to the method, e.g.

```
    public static void GetControl(MainWindow window)
    {
        var Control = window.switchcontrol;
    }
```

if you are going to be passing several different derived types of Window, you could also do this:

```
    public static void GetControl(Window window)
    {
        dynamic SomeTypeOfWindow = window;
        try
        {
            var Control = SomeTypeOfWindow.switchcontrol;
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException)
        {
            // Control Not Found
        }
    }
```